# replace / encode special characters in json response from server?

Tags: android, json

I want to replace or encode  special characters from json response body.
my response is

```
{"form":"\u003Cdiv class=\u0022column\u0022\u003E   \n       
         \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ajxpos col-md-12\u0022 id=\u0022edit-pannel\u0022 style=\u0022margin
```

i already used GsonConverterFactory in my Retrofitclient.But it doesn't work in these case.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

I need to get result like this:

```
String form = "<div class=\"column\">.....
```

any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found a solution :

```
 public static String toPrettyFormat(String jsonString)
    {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject json = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
        String prettyJson = gson.toJson(json);

        return prettyJson;
    }
```